# A question about K-fold cross validation in the context of neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, cross-validation

Let's say that I want to perform K-fold cross validation for a neural network model. So, as usual, I split my dataset D into $K$ different folds. The fold $k$ is the validation fold while the remaining $k-1$ are training folds. My question is: **would it be correct to use the validation fold $k$ as validation set for the neural network, or would this lead to information leakage, if we, for example, use early-stopping or other training schemes that could bias the learning process towards the specific data in the validation?** Personally, my approach so far has been extracting an additional 10% of data from the $k-1$ training folds to be used as validation set for the network, in a way that the validation fold remains completely untouched. Do you think that this approach would eventually be better?

Answer (score 1):

> my approach so far has been extracting an additional 10% of data from the −1 training folds to be used as validation set for the network, in a way that the validation fold remains completely untouched.

I think that is the same as what I was going to say.

I would do ordinary `k`-fold and, within each of the `k` iterations, allocate some small percentage of the `k-1` pool for early stopping. I would *not* reserve one of the `k` folds for any special purpose.

Doing it this way also properly cross-validates the early stopping; a different bit of data is used each of the `k` times, and any negative (or positive) effect of that will correctly propagate to the resampling statistics.

(This is exactly how we designed in R's tidymodels framework)

If you have a *really* large sample, then maybe keep a static early stopping validation set around. Otherwise, make sure to repeat the early stopping process `k` times with different data.